# Failure writing file : Report processing has been canceled by the user

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, ssrs-2014, ssrs-subscription

I have multiple report running by creating subscription.

All reports are generating PDF files to the given drive. However, one report having error:

```
        Failure writing file Filename@timestamp : Report processing has been canceled by the user.
```

This report is working fine from development PC and taking around a minute to get/render the data. However, it’s taking long time in the report server to be rendered.That is, sometimes its rending (taking more than 30 mins) and sometimes not.

Also, there is error while executing under subscription:

```
       Failure writing file Filename@timestamp : Report processing has been canceled by the user.
```

Please note that, no one is cancelling the report, then why am I getting this kind of error message.

Do not time out report "site setting" as well as "individual report".

EDIT:
Got one new error, while just executing report (no subscription):

```
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 12002
```

What is wrong with this? How to debug this? How to fix this issue?

Note: this report query has NOLOCK and deployed in released mode from SSDT.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed if there are potentially any conflicts when you have scheduled the report to run and be put in the drive? Any sort of scheduled process on the db? this could interfere with it.

Comment: Also worth checking, what are the timeout settings on the datasource that the report is using?

Comment: Updated my question. How to check data source timeout setting? What this is?

Comment: If you don't know what datasource it is using, click the dropdown for the report then manage. You should find the datasources tab there. Once you have found the path, go clock on manage for that datasource

Comment: In this case,  it's using the shared data source... Do you want me to set only this report as "A custom data source"??

Comment: No, do you see the path that it is pointing to? Navigate to the datasource on the report server then click the manage option for the datasource. You are only managing the report to identify the datasource.